# akka-persistence with Play Framework

Tags: java, playframework, sbt, akka, akka-persistence

I have setup a [Play Framework](https://www.playframework.com/) project and I want to use [akka-persistence](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/scala/persistence.html) along with it. I downloaded the JAR for akka-persistence and dropped it on the lib folder of my Play project. The akka-persistence classes are recognized and I can compile and run the application, but as soon as the application starts, it throws a `NoClassDefFoundError` exception and the application stops. I have successfully used akka-persistence before (although not with Play Framework project). Any hints?

**Notes**: I'm using Play Framework 2.3.4 (which I believe uses Akka 2.3.4, with the akka-persistence module manually removed). I'm using Java all around (not Scala). The jar for akka-persistence is akka-persistence-experimental_2.11-2.3.4.jar. The exception thrown and the stack trace is the following:

```
[info] play - Application started (Dev)
[info] play - Starting application default Akka system.
Uncaught error from thread [application-akka.persistence.dispatchers.default-plugin-dispatcher-7] shutting down JVM since 'akka.jvm-exit-on-fatal-error' is enabled for ActorSystem[application]
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/iq80/leveldb/DBFactory
    at akka.persistence.journal.leveldb.LeveldbJournal.<init>(LeveldbJournal.scala:20)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:379)
    at akka.util.Reflect$.instantiate(Reflect.scala:45)
    at akka.actor.NoArgsReflectConstructor.produce(Props.scala:361)
    at akka.actor.Props.newActor(Props.scala:252)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.newActor(ActorCell.scala:552)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.create(ActorCell.scala:578)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.invokeAll$1(ActorCell.scala:456)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.systemInvoke(ActorCell.scala:478)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processAllSystemMessages(Mailbox.scala:263)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.run(Mailbox.scala:219)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.iq80.leveldb.DBFactory
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    ... 18 more
[ERROR] [12/16/2014 20:56:12.495] [application-akka.persistence.dispatchers.default-plugin-dispatcher-7] [ActorSystem(application)] Uncaught error from thread [application-akka.persistence.dispatchers.default-plugin-dispatcher-7] shutting down JVM since 'akka.jvm-exit-on-fatal-error' is enabled
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/iq80/leveldb/DBFactory
    at akka.persistence.journal.leveldb.LeveldbJournal.<init>(LeveldbJournal.scala:20)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:379)
    at akka.util.Reflect$.instantiate(Reflect.scala:45)
    at akka.actor.NoArgsReflectConstructor.produce(Props.scala:361)
    at akka.actor.Props.newActor(Props.scala:252)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.newActor(ActorCell.scala:552)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.create(ActorCell.scala:578)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.invokeAll$1(ActorCell.scala:456)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.systemInvoke(ActorCell.scala:478)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processAllSystemMessages(Mailbox.scala:263)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.run(Mailbox.scala:219)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.iq80.leveldb.DBFactory
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    ... 18 more
```

My build.sbt:

```
name := """project-name"""

version := "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

lazy val root = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(PlayJava)

scalaVersion := "2.11.1"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-persistence-experimental" % "2.3.4",
  "org.iq80.leveldb" % "leveldb" % "0.7", // I added this
  "org.fusesource.leveldbjni" % "leveldbjni-all" % "1.8", // and this, because of the jar
  "org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % "2.1.6" % "test",
  "com.amazonaws" % "aws-java-sdk-dynamodb" % "1.9.5"
)

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  javaJdbc,
  javaEbean,
  cache,
  javaWs
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you're missing other transient dependencies that `akka-persistence` depends on. For example by default it depends on:

- `org.fusesource.leveldbjni:leveldbjni-all:1.7`
- `org.iq80.leveldb:leveldb:0.5`
- `com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java:2.5.0`

And all these have further dependencies. Instead of downloading/adding jars manually you should add `akka-persistence` to `libraryDependencies` in your `build.sbt` which will automatically pull in all it's requisite dependencies.

```
libraryDependencies += "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-persistence-experimental" % "2.3.4"
```

Comment: Well, thanks for your answer. The reason I added the jars manually was precisely that adding it to build.sbt didn't work (while other dependencies were working as expected in build.sbt)

Comment: What do you mean when you say it didn't work? What kind of error did you get? You need to make sure you didn't make any typos.

Comment: I even copied the line you posted to try. When I said it didn't work, I meant: 1) I wrote the dependency on build.sbt. 2) sbt updated the project 3) I'm able to access other classes from other libraries I have in build.sbt, but not the ones from akka-persistence. I will append my build.sbt to the question. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Try to remove `leveldb` and `leveldbjni-all` from `libraryDependencies` as those might not be the ones `akka-persistence` depends on.

Comment: That's how it was at the beginning and I get that UntypedPersistentActor doesn't exist (and in general the whole akka-persistence content is unreachable).

Comment: Seems like the problem was with IntelliJ IDEA, not updating the SBT dependencies of the imported Play project. So, technically speaking, your answer is correct. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

Well, the current solution I found is adding this two dependencies to build.sbt:

```
  "org.iq80.leveldb" % "leveldb" % "0.7"

  "org.fusesource.leveldbjni" % "leveldbjni-all" % "1.8"
```

Nonetheless, I would be very happy to hear why such thing solves the issue and if it's well documented somewhere around the web.